# STRING_SPLIT on value from database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to setup a SQL query where I want to get data by tags. The problem is that "Tags" column stores data in comma separated format, for example "tag1,tag2".

Code example:

```
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',')) 
IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('tag1,tag2,tag3', ','));
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery where you join the result sets together:

```
SELECT N.*
FROM News N
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(N.Tags, ',') s1 JOIN
                   STRING_SPLIT('tag1,tag2,tag3', ',') s2
                   ON s1.value = s2.value
             );
```